# El botón de subir imagenes de CKEDITOR no funciona con navegador Mozilla

Tags: asp, firefox

Utilizo el ckeditor en asp .net mvc 4, se inicia bien, al levantar para las imágenes en el navegador de Mozilla , no levanta el poput en cambio en Chrome si funciona y se queda en blanco. dejo un pantallazo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Código:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
            <title>index</title>

            <script src="~/Areas/Admin/Assets/js/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
            <script src="~/Content/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                        $(function () {
                            CKEDITOR.replace('txtCkEditor', { filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '../../../Uploads.ashx' });
                        });

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>

                <input type="text" id="txtCkEditor" />
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Supongo que por "Mozilla" te refieres a "Firefox". El navegador se llama Firefox, Mozilla es el nombre de la compañía.

Comment: CKEditor 4, probado y funcionando en Firefox (entre otros).